# pr2_gazebo_plugins, ROS and Gazebo 1.9

Tags: ros, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi folks.
I'm currently working on a robot and found an URDF file including Gazebo plugins. This file is based on pr2_gazebo_plugins. I'm working on Gazebo 1.9. I managed to spawn my robot in Gazebo but the topics are not feed.

I have read in the document about PR2/Gazebo:

Note: This tutorial refers to a previous version of Gazebo that is no longer fully supported. In the future this tutorial needs to be updated to use the new gazebo_ros_pkgs interface.

Does it mean that the description file should be adapted to gazebo_ros_pkgs? I just want to be sure before breaking everything.

Thx in advance for your answer!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4020/pr2_gazebo_plugins,-ros-and-gazebo-1.9/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 316 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I answer YES to my own question. I have adapted my previous URDF file which was based on pr2_controller to ros_controller. That works very nicely.

---

Originally posted by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) with karma: 316 on 2013-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-08-04**:
Great, I'm glad this worked - ros_controllers is mostly a port of pr2_controllers with the name just being removed